# Modificar el valor de un puntero char

Tags: c

Tengo dos funciones, la `funcionA` le envía el puntero a la `funcionB`, la `funcionB` pide un valor por consola, que luego se lo pasa al puntero. La `funcionA` al querer imprimir el valor del puntero tira basura.

Tengo el siguiente código de la **funcionA**

```
char kilometraje;
pedirKilometros("Ingrese los kilometros: ",&kilometraje);
```

El código de la **funcionB**

```
void pedirKilometros(char mensajeKilometros[],char ** kilometraje){
    char *bufferKilometraje[20];
    scanf("%s",bufferKilometraje);
    strcpy(kilometraje,bufferKilometraje);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> al querer imprimir el valor del puntero tira basura.

Lo sorprendente es que siquiera te compile, pues el código tiene serios errores en los tipos de los datos:

- La variable `kilometraje` es de tipo `char` el operador et (`&`) devuelve la dirección de memoria de una variable, es decir: devuelve un puntero a una variable. Así pues `&kilometraje` es de tipo `char *`.
- Una variable de tipo formación<sup>1</sup> sin tamaño (como `char mensajeKilometros[]`) es interpretada como un puntero al primer elemento de la formación, así que el tipo `char[]` pasa a `char *`.
- Los literales de texto en [c](/questions/tagged/c), tienen como tipo formación de `char` con tamaño estático, en el caso del literal `"Ingrese los kilometros: "` el tipo es `char[25]` que también se interpreta como puntero al primer elemento así que pasa a `char *`.

Sabiendo esto, la función `pedirKilometros` recibe dos parámetros: el primero es de tipo `char[]` que pasa a `char *` (puntero a carácter) y el segundo es `char **` (puntero a puntero a carácter). **Pero**, la llamada a función:

```
pedirKilometros("Ingrese los kilometros: ",&kilometraje);
```

Tiene en el primer argumento `"Ingrese los kilometros: "` que es de tipo `char[25]` que pasa a `char *`. Y de segundo argumento `&kilometraje` que es de tipo `char *` pero esperaba un tipo `char **`. Esto directamente no debería siquiera compilar.

Por otro lado, una variable de tipo `char` sólo puede almacenar **UN** carácter, si la interpretas como si fuese un búfer estarás escribiendo fuera de su espacio de memoria, lo cuál es [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido)<sup>2</sup>.

Probablemente, lo que querías hacer es lo siguiente:

```
// 'kilometraje' es tipo 'char *'
char *kilometraje = NULL;
// '&kilometraje' es tipo 'char **'
pedirKilometros("Ingrese los kilometros: ", &kilometraje);

void pedirKilometros(char mensajeKilometros[],char **kilometraje) {
    *kilometraje = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    scanf("%s", *kilometraje);
}
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o *array* en inglés.

###### <sup>2</sup>Que puede hacer que tu programa se comporte de manera errática, como estás viendo.